# ARToolKit Calibration Result Saving Error

Tags: c++, augmented-reality, artoolkit

I have been using ARToolKit to calibrate my camera, everything went fine until I tried to save the result, it came up with this error:

Error (13): unable to open camera parameters file "camera_para.dat" for writing.
Result too large
Parameter write error!!

I used the ARToolKit's calib_camera example code.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've actually figured this out...it was just because my ARToolKit was installed in Program Files folder, which is read-only. To save the results successfully, all you need to do is to run as administrator at the beginning.